# How to show the diff view of gitlab snippets?

Tags: gitlab, code-snippets

I created a snippet in Gitlab 13.5.3.
According to [Gitlab's Documentation about snippets](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/snippets.html#versioned-snippets) these are version controlled since 13.0.

Is there some way to show the diff view between versions of snippets like in Github?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to show the diff between versions is to clone and then use a git diff.

So far, GitLab has no functionality to display diffs in snippets.

> Revisions are not yet visible to the user on the GitLab UI, but it's
> planned to be added in future iterations. See the revisions tab issue
> for updates.

https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/39271